# Entity Reference Colorbox Format Display

Tags: entities, javascript, media

I'm having trouble in creating an album with many galleries, that reference images through entity reference content type from Biblio. I have tried many ways to create the following. But all partially failed.

In my last try I followed the following tutorial: [Creating-a-drupal-7-image-gallery-using-content-types-nodes_tech](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xnqe4c_creating-a-drupal-7-image-gallery-using-content-types-nodes_tech) , it works out fine with the referenced image.

But couldn't complete the tutorial in the following step: 
I need to change the referenced image format to colorbox, from the Manage Display of Node Image content. Is there way to do the following on a referenced entity?

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manage display change the format for the referenced image to rendered entity. Then select the gearbox and select colorbox view.

You will need to edit this view mode.So go to biblio content type and manage display. Select colorbox view and change the image field format to colorbox.